# Wagmi React hooks - caching

Tags: react, wagmi

I wonder if someone use Wagmi hooks for Ethereum and it's caching mechanism. Since docs doesn't say much about it ([Wagmi docs](https://wagmi.sh/react/hooks/useContractRead#cachetime-optional)) can somebody explain me how it acutualy works?
If i use useContractRead with `scopeKey: 'myScope'` and caching `cacheTime: 1000*60*10 // 10 minutes` then every time my component mounts it should first read the cache and return a cached value instead of using RPC to get value from blockchain, right? Well if it should, then it doesn't work, because every time I switch page I can see that my local hardhat is being asked for values. This means it can drain out RPC query limit very fast. How should I use `cacheTime`? Maybe I should also use `staleTime`?

Answer (score 0):

Both have almost similar but not same functionality, stalTime can serve your purpose but still it fetches the data on mount and dismount.
You can have a look here to get more insights

> https://wagmi.sh/react/hooks/useTransaction